# How to use "for" to "loop" multiple urls while webscraping?

Tags: python, json, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The current code is perfect to scrape the information for only one Url, and i would like to be able to scrape from multiple urls at once ( maybe use For url in Urls ) ,Here is the current code for just one url below. Please any help or direction would be appreciated

```
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_url_data_from_url_request(url):
 print(">> get_url_data_from_url_request: "+str(url))
 url_data = None
 headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 
 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
 Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"}
 s = requests.session()
 s.keep_alive = False
 request = s.get(url, proxies=None, headers=headers)
 print("request.status_code: ", request.status_code )
 url_data = request.text
 request.connection.close()
 s.close()
 return url_data

def main():
 print("bdr.sandbox")
 generated_on = datetime.datetime.now()
 print(generated_on)
 source_product_url = ""
 url_data = get_url_data_from_url_request(url=source_product_url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(url_data, "lxml")
 id_element = soup.find('span', {"itemprop": "sku"}).text
 print(id_element)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: So what's the problem using forloop?

Comment: Please read [Python For Loop Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to understand the question, because it's not clear **why there is a problem**. For example, do you know how to use a `for` loop **for other things**? If so, then why is it a problem to use it for this task? If you don't know, then - how did you know, in the first place, that there is such a thing as a `for` loop? Because you read it somewhere, right? Did you try going back there, and reading some more, to understand how to use it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are countless ways to do it; this is one example: parametrize `source_product_url` in `main` and call it in loop. (Add `return id_element` if you want to save the data for future use.)

```py
def get_sku(source_product_url):
 print("bdr.sandbox")
 generated_on = datetime.datetime.now()
 print(generated_on) 
 url_data = get_url_data_from_url_request(url=source_product_url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(url_data, "lxml")
 id_element = soup.find('span', {"itemprop": "sku"}).text
 print(id_element)
 return id_element
```

You could just do `for url in urlsList: get_sku(url)` at this point, but if you want to  collect some data [and also make sure that, even if any errors are raised while scraping some of the pages, the program still attempts to scrape the rest], then you could do something like

```py
def try_get_sku(srcProdUrl):
 try: return {'source_product_url': srcProdUrl, 'sku': get_sku(srcProdUrl)}
 except Exception as e:
  errorMsg = f'{type(e)} {e}'
  print(f'failed to scrape {srcProdUrl} \n ', errorMsg)
  return {'source_product_url': srcProdUrl, 'errorMsg': errorMsg}
```

( This also facilitates [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) )

```py
def main():
 spUrls = [
  'https://www.6pm.com/p/easy-spirit-epic-gray/product/9450972/color/11',
  ## ADD ALL URLS TO SCRAPE ##
 ]
 productsInfo = [try_get_sku(spUrls) for url in spUrls]
 # do something with productsInfo if you want to, like
 # pandas.DataFrame(productsInfo).to_csv('productsInfo.csv') # saves in csv file [import pandas]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , you the only one who understood my question and gave me the right answer. I really appreciate.